# HHVM CMake error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, hhvm

I am trying to install HHVM on an Ubunut 14.04 machine using this guide:
https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/building-from-source#ubuntu-15.04-vivid

However, when running the cmake -DMYSQL_UNIX_SOCK_ADDR=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock . step i am retuned an error like this:

```
CMake Error in third-party/CMakeLists.txt:
```

Cannot find source file:

```
INTERFACE
```

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx

CMake Warning (dev) in third-party/CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0022 is not set: INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link
  interface.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Target "boost" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property.  This should be
  preferred as the source of the link interface for this library but because
  CMP0022 is not set CMake is ignoring the property and using the link
  implementation as the link interface instead.

INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_context.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
```

Link implementation:

```
(empty)
```

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mihai/hhvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mihai/hhvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

This issue is not happening on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I have searched up and down for a solution and found nothing.

Thank you,
Mihai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you need a newer version of cmake.  It looks like the add_library(name INTERFACE ...) command was added some time after v2.8.12 (which is what ships with ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Thnaks for the answer. I updated the cmake and now i get another erorr when running the "make" command:

heap/hh_shared.o: In function `hh_store_ocaml':
/home/mihai/hhvm/hphp/hack/src/_build/heap/hh_shared.c:1513: undefined reference to `LZ4_compress_default'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
File "caml_startup", line 1:
Error: Error during linking
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 1091 targets (1090 cached) in 00:00:16.

Comment: @MihaiGhimpu maybe a newer version of the lz4-dev library?